# dot_product function case a "syntax error" in fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm new to fortran and now need to produce a dot production of selected row and column in fortran. The code is like (incomplete):

```
    module parameters
implicit none
   REAL, PARAMETER        :: b = 0.99, d = 0.025, a = 0.36
   REAL, PARAMETER        :: klb = 0.01, inc = 0.025, kub = 45.0
   INTEGER, PARAMETER   :: length_grid_k = (kub-klb)/inc + 1
   INTEGER, PARAMETER   :: length_z = 2
   REAL , PARAMETER       :: toler   = 1.e-4             ! Numerical tolerance
   !REAL,DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: P         ! Trasition matrix of technology process
   !REAL,DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: y


end module

! ============================================================================================
module global
USE parameters
implicit none ! change from determinstic case: value fun (value and value_new )is a k*z matrix now
   REAL         :: Kgrid(length_grid_k), value(length_grid_k,length_z), g_k(length_grid_k,length_z)
   REAL                 :: vtmp(length_grid_k,length_grid_k), value_new(length_grid_k,length_z)
end module

! ============================================================================================

PROGRAM  HW2Stochastic
   REAL             :: total, etime, dist
   REAL, DIMENSION(2)       :: elapsed
   REAL, DIMENSION(2,2)   :: P
   REAL, DIMENSION(2)   :: y ! all declarations have to precede all executable statements
   P(1,:) = (/0.977, 0.023/)
   P(2,:) = (/0.074, 0.926/)
   y      = (/1.25, 0.2/)


   call solution

   total=etime(elapsed)


    PRINT*,'--------------------------------------------------'
    PRINT*,'total time elpased =',total
    PRINT*,'--------------------------------------------------'


END PROGRAM HW2Stochastic

! ============================================================================================
subroutine solution
USE parameters
USE global

   IMPLICIT  NONE

   INTEGER :: iter, index_k, index_z, index_kp
   REAL    :: diff, k, kp, c , z, y

   INTEGER :: i = 1, l , m


   do while (i<=length_grid_k)   !do loop for assigning capital grid K
     Kgrid(i) = klb + (i-1)*inc
     !write(*,*) i, Kgrid(i)
     i = i + 1
   end do


   iter = 1
   diff = 1000.d0
   ! value = 0.*Kgrid       !Initial Value guess
   do l = 1, length_z ! Intial value guess in stochastic case, a matrix of zeros
      do m = 1, length_grid_k
        value (l,m) = 0
      end do
   end do    

    do while (diff>= toler)

!------------------
! loop over k(t)
!------------------

        do index_k = 1, length_grid_k               ! Capital grid
             k = Kgrid(index_k)
       vtmp(index_k,:) = -1.0e-16 ! initial matrix used to store value fun


!----------------------------
!  (new) loop over z(t)
!----------------------------  

        do index_z = 1, length_z     
             z = y(index_z)

!-------------------
! loop over k(t+1)
!-------------------    
                         do index_kp = 1, length_grid_k
                            kp = Kgrid(index_kp)
                            c = z*k**a+(1.-d)*k-kp ! add technology shock

                                 if (c>0.) then  
                            vtmp(index_k,index_kp) = log(c)+b*dot_product(P(index_z,:),value(:,index_kp)) ! potential bug, 

                            endif

                          end do

                  value_new(index_k,index_z) = MAXVAL(vtmp(index_k,:)) !Determines the maximum value of the elements in an array value
            g_k(index_k,index_z) = Kgrid(MAXLOC(vtmp(index_k,:),1)) !Collect policy function (but no use in this program)

        end do 
    end do                             ! returns the location of the first element in array having the maximum value (in this case, of each row)

        diff  = maxval(abs(value_new-value))/ABS(value_new(length_grid_k,length_z)) ! different from determinstic 
        value = value_new


        print*, 'Iteration =',iter,'sup_norm =',diff
                iter = iter+1

    enddo

    print *, ' '
    print *, 'Successfully converged with sup_norm ', diff
        !print *, g_k

    !CALL vcDrawCurve@(d, Kgrid, g_k, length_grid_k)


        open (UNIT=1,FILE='valuefun',STATUS='replace')
    do index_k = 1, length_grid_k
     do index_z = 1, length_z
            WRITE(UNIT=1,FMT=*) value(index_k,index_z)
     end do
  end do   
    close (UNIT=1)

end subroutine
```

So you can see `P` is a (lengh_z,length_z) matrix and `value` is a (length_z,length_grid_k) matrix by design.
However, using gfortran 4.6.3, I get the following error message:

```
test.f90:101.84:

                   vtmp(index_k,index_kp) = log(c)+b*dot_product(P(index_z,:),v
```

My fortran compiler's version is gcc-fortran-4.7.2-1-mingw32-bin
                                                                               1
    Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)

[image]

Comment: You've posted *something like* your code, and *something like* the error message your compiler produces.  Post exactly your code and post exactly the error message and you might have some hope of assistance.

Comment: Extending the existing comments: "So you can see `P` is a (lengh_z,length_z) matrix and `value` is a (length_z,length_grid_k) matrix ...".  Well, no, we can't see that since you didn't provide the declarations.

Comment: I have corrected the format so error message is not in code format, thank you @HighPerformanceMark.

Comment: I also add the complete code, so you can see the declarations now, thanks @francescalus

Comment: `P` is defined in your main program but not in your subroutine `solution`. Use an interface, or better put `solution` in a module and `use` that module in your program. I am not sure if you meant to use `P` from your main program, which is a 2x2 array, since `value` has size 1800x2. Also, all your arrays defined in `global` have size `length_grid_k`x`length_z`, where `length_grid_k` is calculated based on `real` numbers.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't told us *exactly* what the error message is.  And now I'd like to know how you are compiling this code and the name of the file containing the code

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've shown us your code and exactly what the compiler is complaining about the problem is blindingly obvious.  Somehow your compiler is seeing only part of the line where it finds the error, specifically the part:

```
               vtmp(index_k,index_kp) = log(c)+b*dot_product(P(index_z,:),v
```

That's not a syntactically-valid fragment, hence the error.

It's difficult to say why the compiler is only reading the first 80 characters of the line since you haven't shown us how you compile it.  But one solution is to be a little less enthusiastic about indentation and to move that line about 16 characters to the left.

Another solution would be to tell your compiler to expect longer lines -- its documentation will tell you how.

I'm sure this is a duplicate question but I don't have time to look for an original now.

And, as already noted, that gross syntax error is not the only mistake in your code, it is merely the one which prompted the error message.

Comment: Well , I add the screen snap this time.  it seems compiler believe I lose one parentheses at the end of the `dot_product` function which I don't. it happens at the 60th character postion which clearly not exceed the 80 characters threshold. My fortran compiler's version is gcc-fortran-4.7.2-1-mingw32-bin